# Why the content assist shows unimported classes?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, content-assist

For example, When I want to create a reference type of TextView :

```
TextView tv;
```

I receive an error which tells me to import android.widget.TextView.

Now, I know how the whole Import packages concept works, but I always wondered how does the Content Assist of eclipse displays the TextView Class of android BEFORE I imported it to my project? how it knows it even exists and how it know it exists in android.widget.TextView.

Thanks!

Comment: eclipse searches the class path for possible matching classes.  The class may not be imported, but exists in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you have already imported the android library into your project. you can try this: open project properties -> click Java Build Path -> choose Libraries -> remove android library. then content assist will not work.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that out :). so in other words I have the android path but I have to import the right packages(only ones I use) to each Class so I will able to use them, right? because importing the ENTIRE android packages to one class is wrong, no?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you must have installed the Android SDK in eclipse. And as part of the sdk that class is available to eclipse and it provides it as part of code assist.